# Efficiency of splitting very long transliteration in Perl

Tags: performance, perl, processing-efficiency, transliteration

I have this very long transliteration:

```
$text =~ tr/áàăâǎåǻäǟãȧǡąāȁȃɑʙƀɓƃćĉčċçȼƈɕʗďđðɖɗƌȡéèĕêěëėȩęēȅȇɇɛ/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbcccccccccdddddddeeeee/;
# Etc. (About 400 chars)
```

I want to split it into several transliterations since the resulting code would be easier to maintain:

```
$text =~ tr/áàăâǎåǻäǟãȧǡąāȁȃɑ/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/;
$text =~ tr/ʙƀɓƃ/bbbb/;
$text =~ tr/ćĉčċçȼƈɕʗ/ccccccccc/;
# Etc.
```

I believe that is going to slow things down, but I'd like to know for sure.  This process runs about 1000 times per second on a pretty busy server.

Thanks.

Comment: ``tr`` and regex are two different things. ``tr`` just translates characters so there's no reason why a longer one should be slower than a short one.

Comment: several times per second?  use Benchmark to measure the time it actually takes, then decide if it is even worth thinking about.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I just edited the question.  The terminology was wrong and I wasn't very clear about my goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a benchmark:

```
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $str = 'áàăâǎåǻäǟãȧǡąāȁȃɑʙƀɓƃćĉčċçȼƈɕʗďđðɖɗƌȡéèĕêěëėȩęēȅȇɇɛ/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbcccccccccdddddddeeeee';
my $count = -2;
cmpthese($count, {
    'one tr' => sub {
        $str =~ tr/áàăâǎåǻäǟãȧǡąāȁȃɑʙƀɓƃćĉčċçȼƈɕʗďđðɖɗƌȡéèĕêěëėȩęēȅȇɇɛ/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbcccccccccdddddddeeeee/;
    },
    'multi tr' => sub {
        $str =~ tr/áàăâǎåǻäǟãȧǡąāȁȃɑ/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/;
        $str =~ tr/ʙƀɓƃ/bbbb/;
        $str =~ tr/ćĉčċçȼƈɕʗ/ccccccccc/;
        $str =~ tr/ďđðɖɗƌȡ/ddddddd/;
        $str =~ tr/éèĕêěëėȩęēȅȇɇɛ/eeeee/;
    },
});
```

**result:**

```
              Rate multi tr   one tr
multi tr 1215538/s       --     -81%
one tr   6271883/s     416%       --
```

As we see, one tr is 5 times faster than multi-tr.

Answer (score 7):

You could build a transliterator:

```
my %translits = (
   'áàăâǎåǻäǟãȧǡąāȁȃɑ' => 'a',
   'ʙƀɓƃ'              => 'b',
   'ćĉčċçȼƈɕʗ'         => 'c',
);

my $pat  = '';
my $repl = '';
for (keys(%translit)) {
   $pat  .= $_;
   $repl .= $translit{$_} x length($_);
}

my $tr1 = eval "sub { tr/\Q$pat\E/\Q$repl\E/ }" or die $@;
   -or-
my $tr2 = eval "sub { \$_[0] =~ tr/\Q$pat\E/\Q$repl\E/ }" or die $@;
```

Then use it like this:

```
$tr1->() for $str;
   -or-
$tr2->($str);
```

Of course, you could always use [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aUnidecode).

Comment: Your code is very clever.  It solves the maintenance problem I'm having, thank you very much.  However, I will have to accept the last answer since it responds the question more directly.  About `Text::Unicode`, I tried it, but it works in mysterious ways and my faith is weak these days.

Answer (score 4):

I would expect the second solution with three operations to be slower, because it re-scans characters in `$text` that have already been substituted.

Comment: That's a good point. Each individual ``tr`` should be the same speed regardless of how many characters are in it. But running it more than once should be slower.

Comment: @acfrancis: What makes you think that the length of the translation set and the type of its elements don't matter? Each input character has to be checked against every character or character class in the translation set, so I would expect the size of the latter and the type of its elements to make a difference.

Comment: Let me add that I'm thinking about the general case; with fixed characters in the translation set, a hash might give constant speed, but with character classes, I don't see how. And even with a hash, a bigger hash needs more computing power to set up...

Comment: Within reason, I would expect Perl to implement ``tr`` with something like a hashtable (each char on the left is a key and the corresponding char on the right is the value) which is able to access any individual key in O(1) regardless of the number of keys. If you had a pathological ``tr`` with millions of characters, that might not be true, but for everyday use, I'll bet it is.

Comment: I missed that second comment before I replied. Are character classes allowed in a ``tr``? I thought they weren't but I might be wrong. Either way, the bigger setup cost is paid at compile time, not execution.

Comment: Ugh, I confused perl's `tr` with `tr(1)`, sorry for that.

Comment: If the input and output sets weren't distinct, splitting a `tr` could even change the semantics by mistake. Looks like that's not the case for calvillo, but anyone else reading this question should be careful :)

Comment: It seems like user2719058 was right.  I tested the accepted response with a sample of the actual data I'm processing, and the results are consistant:  it increases 100% per each new transliteration.  I'll try ikegami's solution.